# Upload file wordpress

Tags: wordpress, permissions, file-permissions

I am trying to upload a file in wordpress using the `Media > Add New` -- Option but when I click upload I get the following error:

> Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2012/11. Is its parent
>   directory writable by the server?

I have Wordpress 4.3.1 installed.

Thank you

EDIT: 
I am on a shared server with: host=i686-redhat-linux-gnu and Apache. I changed the permissions to 755 and 777 of wp-content/uploads but I get the following error:

> “my_file.jpg” has failed to upload due to an error Unable to create
>   directory wp-content/uploads/2012/11. Is its parent directory writable
>   by the server?

Any ideas?

Comment: What operating system and web server do you have?

Comment: did you run `chmod` with the `-R` option to make it recursive? if not, you may have only changed `/wp-content/uploads` and not `/wp-content/uploads/2012`

Comment: if you run `ls -la` on the `/wp-content/uploads` directory, what is the owner and permissions set to? Do you know what user Apache runs as?

Comment: I do not have console access to the server, how could I run the mentioned command? Thx :)

Comment: If you don't have access how did you change the permissions/owner?

Comment: filezilla, current permissions are 755

Comment: can you see the owner? if it's your user, it might not be accessible to the apache user.

Comment: using http://php.net/manual/es/function.fileowner.php i get that folder owner is user 'root' and using http://php.net/manual/es/function.fileperms.php throws me that the permissions are 755, reviewing the info throw by phpinfo() I can see in apache2handler that User/Group: apache(48)/30

Comment: I can guarantee you that Apache isn't running as root, so that is your problem. You either need to change the directory owner to the Apache user, or make it globally writeable with 777 (not preferred)

Comment: @doublesharp, so this begs the question... If Apache is not running as root, how did it create an uploads folder owned by root? That is what needs to be fixed. methinks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set folder permissions for /uploads/ and possibly for /wp-content/ , too.

Typically, both folders should be 755. You may have to *temporarily* raise /uploads/ to 777 and upload an image (this will also force the server to change the folder permissions and user to the correct settings), *but change it back to 755 right away.*

It's easiest to set permissions with an FTP client. See [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) and [FTP Clients « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/FTP_Clients).

And see [Changing File Permissions « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions) for the correct Wordpress permission settings:

> **From the codex.wordpress:** Typically, all files should be owned by your user (ftp) account on your web server, and should be writable by that account. On shared
>   hosts, files should never be owned by the webserver process itself
>   (sometimes this is www, or apache, or nobody user).
>
> Any file that needs write access from WordPress should be owned or
>   group-owned by the user account used by the WordPress (which may be
>   different than the server account). For example, you may have a user
>   account that lets you FTP files back and forth to your server, but
>   your server itself may run using a separate user, in a separate
>   user group, such as dhapache or nobody. If WordPress is running as the
>   FTP account, that account needs to have write access, i.e., be the
>   owner of the files, or belong to a group that has write access. In the
>   latter case, that would mean permissions are set more permissively
>   than default (for example, 775 rather than 755 for folders, and 664
>   instead of 644).

Answer (score 3):

ssh in and navigate to the `wp-content` folder and type in these 2 lines:

```
sudo chown -R www-data uploads/
sudo chmod -R 755 uploads/
```

or you can use the static and full path:

```
sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/wp-content/uploads/
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/wp-content/uploads/
```

Do not change it to permissions 777 because that is simply insecure

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problems last week. After trying all proposed solutions with no success, it occurred to me that we had SElinux enabled on the server. In my case, and maybe for many other people, SElinux was responsible of the error message:

```
Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2013/04. Is its parent directory writable by the server?
```

My solution is based on the one proposed here: http://doc-ok.org/?tag=selinux which could be more suitable to other people's needs.

In my case, my wordpress directory resides in my home folder on the server, to which I have ssh access. Otherwise you will have to ask your administrator.

Anyway, this is my solution.

```
chgrp -R apache wordpress #change wordpress with your base directory for wp..
#alternatively, chown the whole directory to apache
chmod -R 774 wordpress/wp-content #if chown by apache, the permissions can be more restrictive
```

In my case not only the folder ownership / group ownership had to be  changed to apache. Also the SElinux label of wp-content directory had to be changed to either httpd_sys_rw_content_t or httpd_sys_content_t:

```
chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_content_t wordpress/wp-content
```

This did the trick for me.

More information on SElinux can be found for example at:

wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux

and

fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux

Comment: In my case the /uploads directory was already "httpd_sys_content_t" but it was still giving me the error. I had to change it to "httpd_sys_rw_content_t" in order for me to work

Answer (score 1):

The `/wp-content/uploads` directory needs to be writeable by your webserver. Assuming that you are using Apache on Linux, and that it is running as user `apache` (change to your appropriate user) one quick fix for this would be to run the following command from your web root.

```
chown -R apache.apache wp-content/uploads
chmod -R 755 wp-content/uploads
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and I found a better solution:

1. go to cpanel > phpmyadmin
2. select database
3. open wp_options table
4. make sql query `SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name LIKE '%upload_path%'`
5. change the path

Answer (score 1):

this should fix it.

```
    sudo chown -R www-data:www-data wp-content/uploads
```

Do not change the permissions to 755 if it's not necessary.
If it still doesn't work try:

```
    chmod -R 755 wp-content/uploads
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me, after many weeks headache

```
sudo chown -R apache uploads
sudo chmod -R 755 uploads
```

assuming you're in `wp-content`

Answer (score 0):

for those who stumbled on selinux permission issue, here are the steps i made to fix them. We need to allow the following selinux boolean variables to allow installing of wordpress plugins from wordpress admin console using FTP. They are httpd_can_network_connect and ftpd_full_access. They can be activated by

**setsebool ftpd_full_access on**

**setsebool httpd_can_network_connect on**

also wp-content folder should be write permissible for the ftp user used for uploading.